# is this way of inheritance wrong?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, composition, aggregation

I don't know whether I chose a good title or not but I'm developing a simple card-based game and this is my scenario:

I have a Class called **Player** and I have instantiated few objects ( lets say 4 ) from Player. On each round of game we have a special kind of player lets say **SpecialPlayer** that on each round one of those 4 Players can be SpecialPlayer.

SpecialPlayer is a simple Player plus it can do some more stuff, lets say pause/restart the game. So I inherited from the Player and created SpecialPlayer and added 2 methods to that class.
The problem is , when I instantiate SpecialPlayer , I will have another object plus those 4 player objects , thats Ok, but I want to be able to change properties in SpecialPlayer and see the effects on the Player object who was SpecialPlayer on that round

For example each Player can Score points , I want to see that SpecialPlayer score a point and change the score and its effects on the Player object.

Is inheritance here is wrong? do I have to compose Player class in the SpecialPlayer class?

If it may change the answer , I have to say I'm using **Ruby**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to have to disagree with others and tell you this sounds like you need to extend your `Player` *instance* with a `SpecialPlayer` module. Let me demonstrate. Let's say you have a player class:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :game

  def special?
    false
  end
end
```

All players will have these methods. Let's create a new player:

```
player = Player.new
player.game = Game.new
player.special? # false
```

Now let's say you have your `SpecialPlayer` module:

```
module SpecialPlayer
  def special?
    true
  end

  def pause_game
    game.pause
  end

  def restart_game
    game.restart
  end
end
```

Your module doesn't yet alter `Player` behavior because you have not done anything to your player. So let's extend our player instance with `SpecialPlayer`:

```
player.extend SpecialPlayer
player.special? # true
player.pause_game # pauses the game
player.restart_game # restarts the game
```

The beauty of this is that any other players in the system don't have to care about who is special or how they got that way:

```
other_player = Player.new
other_player.special? # false
other_player.pause_game # NoMethodError: undefined method `pause_game' for #<Player>
other_player.restart_game # NoMethodError: undefined method `restart_game' for #<Player>
```

This also ensures that not just any player can be special. Calling `#restart_game` from a non-special player won't even work, so you won't have bugs where regular players are doing things they shouldn't.

Comment: I really like your solution , it is Ruby way of handling it

Answer (score 2):

Since the SpecialPlayer object should replace a Player object at the end of each round, I think it would be more appropriate NOT to create a SpecialPlayer class to extend Player.

I would instead add a flag to the Player to mark it as special (boolean special) and according to that I would know if he can perform special functions.

Comment: Thats a good way of handling it , but I was thinking about if there is another way to handle it , because image if Special Player have a lot of data and methods which might occupy a lot of resources in the ram ?

Comment: Don't worry about that. I can't imagine that the memory taken by the extra data would be too much. And the amount of memory taken by methods is "fixed overhead"; it doesn't increase with the number of object instances created.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the Decorator pattern. You can create a SpecialPlayer class with the same interface (IPlayer) as the regular Player class. The SpecialPlayer class would also have a player attribute (pointer to the Player who is special), and an assignPlayer method, which is called at the end of every round to set the player attribute to the pointer to the new special player. All methods of the SpecialPlayer class which are inherited from IPlayer should call the corresponding method from the player attribute.

Comment: I'm using ruby , so there is no Interface, because it is a dynamic language

Comment: I've asked same question today from my course lecturer and he pointed to the decorator too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want the behaviour of a `Player` to vary depending on whether it is special or not. In this type of problems it is useful to encapsulate the varying behavior in an interface (`IHandling`) and let the original class depend on an implementation of this interface. In your case you would let the `Player` delegate varying behaviour to either a `SpecialHandling` or `NormalHandling`. Your normal handling could do nothing. After each round, the `SpecialHandling` object can be attached to another `Player`.

Points should be stored in the `Player` class since this is common functionality. However, suppose points were to be multiplied for a `Player` using the `SpecialHandling`, you would have the `Player` class delegate this to the `IHandling` instance.